# CGI (Commong Gateway Interface) program example wont run from HTML page

Tags: python, apache-httpd, html, cgi

I'm trying to run this example CGI program that is from this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

The HTML code is as follows, the file is named "add.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="add.cgi" method="POST">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Enter two numbers to add</legend>
     <label>First Number: <input type="number" name="num1"></label><br/>
     <label>Second Number: <input type="number" name="num2"></label><br/>
   </fieldset>
   <button>Add</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

while the CGI code is as follows, the file is called "add.cgi"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

input_data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print('Content-Type: text/html') # HTML is following
print('')                         # Leave a blank line
print('<h1>Addition Results</h1>')
try:
    num1 = int(input_data["num1"].value)
    num2 = int(input_data["num2"].value)
except:
    print('<output>Sorry, the script cannot turn your inputs into numbers (integers).</output>')
    raise SystemExit(1)
print('<output>{0} + {1} = {2}</output>'.format(num1, num2, num1 + num2))
```

My apache config files are located at

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo vim 000-default.conf
```

and the code there is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf 




</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And the Apache config files are located here

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/etc/apache2$ sudo vim apache2.conf
```

The code in the apache2.conf is as follows

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet


#########     Adding capaility to run CGI-scripts #################
ServerName localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

While I also have the add.html and add.cgi both in the following directory

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo vim add.cgi
User@User-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo vim add.html
```

I've attempted to make them executable by doing the following commands

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo chmod a+x add.cgi
User@User-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/cgi-bin$ sudo chmod a+x add.html
```

I also have these files on the desktop

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/home/User/Desktop$ sudo vim add.cgi
User@User-VirtualBox:/home/User/Desktop$ sudo vim add.html
```

Now, when I try to run the add.html from the following url

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/add.html
```

I get a "Forbidden" permission, not allowed.

[image: Forbidden]

Then when I try to use the add.html program from the desktop I get the following HTML page

[image: HTML page]

but when I click add I only get the source code to the CGI script located at the desktop

[image: CGI Page]

Does anybody have any advice on how to make the script work? I would very much appreciate any input, Thank you.

**Update:** I've moved the files into the following directory, gave permission to run and reloaded apache using the following commands

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/$ cd /var/www/html
User@User-VirtualBox: /var/www/html$ sudo vim add.cgi
User@User-VirtualBox: /var/www/html$ sudo vim add.html
User@User-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ sudo chmod a+x add.cgi
User@User-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ sudo chmod a+x add.html
User@User-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$ systemctl reload apache2
```

The add.html file loads

[image: add.html ex]

However I still encounter the same problem when pressing the add button

[image: add.cgi ex]

The following are the last two error codes that apache gave out

```
User@User-VirtualBox:/var/www/html$     sudo tail -n 2 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sat Jul 24 23:09:12.993845 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 782:tid 139660732775488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 24 23:09:12.993855 2021] [core:notice] [pid 782:tid 139660732775488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Unfortunately not, I still get the same errors

Comment: try putting the cgi script in `/var/www/html`

Comment: Also be nice to know what the apache logs said.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Unfortunately It returned with the same results as before, however I've updated the question with the error logs as well

Comment: You may as well delete all the screen shots that say `file://` in the url, those certainly won't work and do nothing. The only question is why that one at the top says forbidden and I have no idea, but my guess is that the server can't read the script or the /usr/bin/env or python.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Thank you, I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

However, your script is called `add.cgi` you'll want this if that's the case,

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```